# Defining a JavaScript regular expression that matches anything except a particular string

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok, I'm feeling pretty thick right now. Basically, I want to define a JavaScript regular expression that will match anything *except* precisely a particular string. So say I have the string

```
"dog"
```

or

```
"cat"
```

I want a single standalone regular expression such that it will match the string

```
"dogsled"
```

or the string

```
"cattle"
```

Just not "dog" or "cat" on its own. I've tried this, which basically says, ignore anything beginning with "cat" or "dog", which is not exactly what I need...

```
var pattern= /^(?!dog|cat).+/

pattern.test("cat") // false, as expected
pattern.test("dog") // false, as expected
pattern.test("bananananana") // true
pattern.test("dogsled") // false, but the regexp I want would return true
```

This has to be simple.... thanks!

**Edit**
Just to clarify, I don't want to do any negation of return values to get the result I want- the regex should return false for "dog" and true for "dogsled" or false for "cat" and true for "cattle"

Comment: +1 for actually giving the regex a go. So many [tag:regex] questions are just "I can has code" style.

Comment: Why not simply negate? `!string.match(/^dog|cat$/)`

Comment: @LinusKleen ha ha ha great username for a regex question :-)

Comment: Wait, why not `str != "dog"`?

Comment: @LinusKleen- thanks, but I'm explicitly trying to avoid negation of the return value to get what I want- that is, I want a pure regex that will return true or false to the case above

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would opt for simply negating a match as noted in [Linus Kleen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8853357/390989). However, if you absolutely must do it all in regex (or for the learning experience or something) then I think the following should work:

```
^((dog|cat(?!$)).+|(?!dog|cat).+)$
```

This uses two negative lookaheads in an alternation. The first says "Match `cat` or `dog` if it is not followed by the end of string character (`$`), followed by anything else". This matches `dogsled` and `cats` and things of that nature.

The second half of the alternation says "Make sure the beginning of the string (`^`) is not followed by `dog` or `cat` (so it doesn't start with either of those), then match anything". This gets you any word that doesn't begin with `cat` or `dog` (like `banana`).

[Here's an example on regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=%5E%28%28dog%7Ccat%28?!$%29%29.%2b%7C%28?!dog%7Ccat%29.%2b%29$&input=dog%0Adogs%0Adogsled%0Acat%0Acats%0Acatty%0Abanana%0Aplacated%0Aducat%0A%0A).

Comment: Excellent. Plus two (if I could).

Comment: @eldarerathis- the requirement for regex only matching is down to integration constraints, and this fits nicely! Simple negation would have been my preference too, but this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I seem to recall negative look-ahead assertions (`(?! ... )`) to be not fully supported in all Javascript interpreters. A simple negation on the result of the regex should suffice as well, no?

```
var pattern = /^cat|dog$/;

!pattern.test("cat");           // => false
!pattern.test("dog");           // => false
!pattern.test("bananananana");  // => true
!pattern.test("dogsled");       // => true
```

Comment: Really? I know JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds, but I wasn't aware of any problems with lookaheads (either positive or negative).

Answer (score 0):

i think this should do the trick:

```
/^(dog|cat)?.+/
```

Comment: This matches both `dog` and `cat`.